# compare data.frames with different number for rows

Tags: r, compare, row, addition, row-number

I have two dataframes:

```
df1<- data.frame(POS=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
             A=c(0.2,0,0,0.8,0),
             G=c(0,0.3,0,0.2,0.5),
             T=c(0.4,0.7,1,0,0.5),
             C=c(0.4,0,0,0,0))

df2<- data.frame(POS=c(1, 3, 4, 5, 6),
             A=c(0.3,0,0.6,0,0),
             G=c(0,0,0.4,0.7,1),
             T=c(0.2,1,0,0.3,0),
             C=c(0.5,0,0,0,0))
```

I'd like to get the summed squared differences for each POS

The first thing I need are two matrices of the same dimensions. How do I add a row for the missing positions filled with 0's?

Once I have the two matrices, I'll do (df1-df2)^2 followed by a rowsums approach.

**To summarize: How do I add a new row filled with zeros for the missing rows in each data.frame?**

like this:

```
POS A   G   T   C
1 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.4
2 0.0 0.3 0.7 0.0
3 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
4 0.8 0.2 0.0 0.0
5 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0
6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

POS A   G   T   C
1 0.3 0.0 0.2 0.5
2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
4 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0
5 0.0 0.7 0.3 0.0
6 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by Zheyuan Li in the comments, you can use `merge()` of each df with the POS column of the other one df on the first column(POS). This adds missing rows which are filled with `NA` so you then have to fill them with zeros :

```
df1 <- merge(df1, df2$POS, all = TRUE, by=1)
df1[is.na(df1)] <- 0
df1
  POS   A   G   T   C
1   1 0.2 0.0 0.4 0.4
2   2 0.0 0.3 0.7 0.0
3   3 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
4   4 0.8 0.2 0.0 0.0
5   5 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0
6   6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

df2 <- merge(df2, df1$POS, all = TRUE, by=1)
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0
df2
  POS   A   G   T   C
1   1 0.3 0.0 0.2 0.5
2   2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   3 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
4   4 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0
5   5 0.0 0.7 0.3 0.0
6   6 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: This works for the example given, however I am having difficulty implementing this into my real data. I am getting errors related to the 'BY'. 
`Error in merge.data.table(mass, evo$POS, all = TRUE, by.x = "POS", by.y = 1) : 
  A non-empty vector of column names are required for by.x and by.y.`
or `Error in merge.data.table(mass, evo$POS, all = TRUE, by = "POS") : 
  Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y`

Comment: Could you explain why you choose `by=1`?
My understanding of the `merge()` is to use the column name to be used (i.e. POS)